# Making a fairly complex Django model method sortable in admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a reasonably complex custom Django model method. It's visible in the admin interface, and I would now like to make it sortable in the admin interface too.

I've added `admin_order_field` as recommended [in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491766/how-to-add-a-sortable-count-column-to-the-django-admin-of-a-model-with-a-many-to), but I don't fully understand what else I need to do.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    library_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def current_owner(self):
        latest_transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(book=self)[:1]
        if latest_transaction:
            if latest_transaction[0].transaction_type==0:
                return latest_transaction[0].user.windows_id
        return None
    current_owner.admin_order_field = 'current_owner'
```

Currently, when I click on the current_owner field in the admin interface, Django gives me

```
FieldError at /admin/books/book/
Cannot resolve keyword 'current_owner' into field
```

Do I need to make a BookManager too? If so, what code should I use? This isn't a simple Count like the example in the previous question, so help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django admin won't order models by the result of a method or any other property that isn't a model field (i.e. a database column). The ordering must be done in the database query, to keep things simple and efficient.

The purpose of `admin_order_field` is to equate the ordering of a non-field property to the ordering of something that is a field.

For example, a valid values `current_owner.admin_order_field` could be `id`, `title` or `library_id`. Obviously none of these makes sense for your purpose.

One solution would be to denormalise and always store `current_owner` as a model field on `Book`; this could be done automatically using a signal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. `admin_order_field` has to be a field, not a method - it's meant for when you have a method that returns a custom representation of an underlying field, not when you do dynamic calculations to provide the value. Django's admin uses the ORM for sorting, and that can't sort on custom methods.