# Django: Any way to sort on model method in admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400) 
    def transactions_all_time(self):
        latest_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(book=self, transaction_type=0)
        return len(latest_transactions)
class Transaction(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    transaction_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES)
```

I'd really like to find a way to list a table of books by title and `transactions_all_time` in the admin interface, and make this table sortable on the `transactions_all_time` field (or simply the number of related transactions, if that's easier).

I know that [there isn't a straightforward way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625414/making-a-fairly-complex-django-model-method-sortable-in-admin) - could anyone suggest a possible approach? Could I write some kind of custom admin view?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't call `len()` on the queryset to get the number of items as it will not translate to sql's `COUNT` but fetch all items of the database instead. Better use the [queryset's `count()` method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count):

`latest_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(book=self, transaction_type=0).count()`

Sorting by a `ForeignKey`'s count should be possible with something like that:

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = Book.objects.filter(transaction_type=0) \
                .annotate(num_transactions=Count('transaction')) \
                .order_by('-num_transactions')
```

For instructions on how to add a sortable column to django's admin [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491766/how-to-add-a-sortable-count-column-to-the-django-admin-of-a-model-with-a-many-to)!

Comment: Thanks! Unless I'm missing something though, the link doesn't say how to add a sortable column to Django's admin - which is the absolutely critical thing I need to do? Sorry, maybe I'm just being an idiot but I don't see it.

Comment: Sorry I've posted the wrong link. See the first answer from the updated link above!

Answer (score 1):

The queryset used by an admin is exposed through the method queryset().  Neither my answer or lazerscience's deals with your transaction type.  So I went back to my example and said, "Those are only the awards those films tried to win.  What if I only wanted those awards the films actually won?"  That addresses your issue of counting only by those transactions of a certain type.  Provided your SQL server supports the count() method internally (it had better!) the answer is:

```
class FilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(FilmAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.extra(
            select = { 'award_count': 'select count(*) from films_filmaward where films_filmaward.film_id=films_film.id and films_filmaward.won=1' }
        )
        qs = qs.order_by('award_count')
        return qs
```

Additionally, if you want to display the award_count in your list, be aware that since it's not a native field of the model it won't be available when the admin builds its list builder factory.  You can work around this by adding the following to your ModelAdmin class:

```
    def award_count(self, obj):
        return obj.award_count

    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'year', 'contact', 'award_count')
```

The list builder factory will see that there's a method for generating the award count, and that method will have access to the rows generated by your queryset.  Viola', there you go.