# django count of foreign key model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi i want to display a count of answers to my question model

my model:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

my view:

```
def all_questions(request):

    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=questions).count()

    return render(request, 'all_questions.html', {
            'questions':questions, 'answers':answers })
```

Right now view displays count of all answers. How can i filter it by the `Question` model?

Comment: If you want this in the Django Admin, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4547426/148439

Comment: nice showcase for those `annotate` methods

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can **use `.annotate()`** to get the count of `answers` associated with each `question`.

```
from django.db.models import Count
questions = Question.objects.annotate(number_of_answers=Count('answer')) # annotate the queryset
```

By doing this, each `question` object will have an extra attribute `number_of_answers` having the value of number of `answers` associated to each `question`.

```
questions[0].number_of_answers # access the number of answers associated with a question using 'number_of_answers' attribute
```

**Final Code:**

```
from django.db.models import Count

def all_questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects.annotate(number_of_answers=Count('answer'))
    return render(request, 'all_questions.html', {
            'questions':questions})
```

In your template, then you can do something like:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    {{question.number_of_answers}} # displays the number of answers associated with this question
```

Answer (score 6):

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)
You can annotate the Query, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
questions = Question.objects.annotate(num_answer=Count('answer'))
```

but, refactor the code to this.
Remove the count of answers:

```
def all_questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all_questions.html', {'questions':questions })
```

Now, in `all_question.html`. Just use :

```
{% for question in questions %}
    Title: {{question.title}}
    Count Answers: {{question.answer_set.all|length}}
    {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
        {{answer.text}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is more efficienty.

Comment: thank you, its worked! i use second advice. But i dont understand about Count, i need to add this field in my Question model?

Comment: you doesnt need use the annotate in this case.. just use length on html

Comment: i did so, its worked. I'm sorry if I ask stupid questions, just tryed understand how Count works. As I understand, if i add Count field in my model like    `count = Question.objects.annotate(num_answer=Count('answer'))`   i can use this in my template        `{{ question.count }}`

Comment: you doenst need add the field count in the model, the 'annotate' .
When an annotate() clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet will be annotated with the specified values.

Comment: Hello @PauloPessoa is there any performance advantage of your solution as opposed to the first answer? Thank you!