# Django's ListView - How to customise it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I did not find any answer to my question.

**My issue below**

I am really struggling to understand how to customise my views when using ListView. I read the Django documentation, but I find it very brief.

What I would like to do is to **count the questions for each topic** and **return the topic with the most questions**. I would be able to count the number of questions for each topic with the following line of code in my models.py (Topic class):

```
def questions_count(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(question__topic = self).count()
```

However, I would like to return only the most popular Topic and the number of questions.

Using a function-based view, I would loop over the topics, and I would create two variables storing the topic name and the number of questions. However, with the ListView I do not know whether to use get_context_data(), get_queryset() or something else.

**My view class**:

```
class TopicsView(ListView):
    model = Topic
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

**My models**:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Question(models.Model):
    ....
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using `.annotate()` to get the count of `Questions` associated with each `Topic`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

topics_count = Topics.objects.annotate(count_of_questions=Count('question'))
```

Each `Topic` object will have a new attribute `count_of_questions` which is the total number of questions associated with each `Topic`.

In your `ListView`:

```
class TopicsView(ListView):
    model = Topic
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(TopicsView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(count_of_questions=Count('question'))
```

Then you should be able to use [dictsortreversed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed) to do the following in your template, which *should* return the topic with the most questions **first**:

```
{% for t in topics|dictsortreversed:"count_of_questions" %}
    {{ t.count_of_questions }}
{% endfor %}
```

There's a similar question and answer in the following [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998591/django-count-of-foreign-key-model)

Comment: Thank you for your question. However, I am looking to return only the Topic instance with the most questions. I do not want to return a queryset.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment -- if you want to use Django's `ListView` this is the most efficient method. In your solution you are adding to `get_context_data()` and I am adding to `get_queryset()` -- no real difference there. To only show the `Topic` with the most questions, just limit the results in your template to the first record? It might help if you explain what you trying to accomplish with getting the count of questions in a variable (like an if/else statement or something)?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have managed to do it through the get_context_data() function. This is how my solution looks like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    mostQuestions = context['object_list'][0].questions_count()
    mostQuestionsTopic = context['object_list'][0]

    for topic in context['object_list']:
        if topic.questions_count() > mostQuestions:
            mostQuestions = topic.questions_count()
            mostQuestionsTopic = topic

    context['mostQuestions'] = mostQuestions
    context['mostQuestionsTopic'] = mostQuestionsTopic

    return context
```

Is there a more efficient solution?