# Django count all child models from parent in one query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to count all children from my parent model but I cannot make It work.

See below for my model and things that I have tried.

Model

```
class ParentXX(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)

class ChildrenXX(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
    parent_sample = models.ForeignKey(ParentXX,
                                      models.CASCADE,
                                      blank=False,
                                      null=False,
                                      related_name='child_sample')
```

Code

```
cnt = ParentXX.objects.filter(name="xx").annotate(c_count=Count('child_sample')) #Not working
cnt = ParentXX.objects.filter(name="xx").annotate(c_count=Count('parent_sample')) #Not working
print(c_count)
```

Comment: Maybe this:  `cnt = ParentXX.objects.annotate(number_of_children=Count('children'))`, [This answer here might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998591/django-count-of-foreign-key-model)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a property for each of the filtered values. To get the count of children for a specific item in the queryset, you would have to reference that annotation.

```
qs = ParentXX.objects.filter(name="xx").annotate(c_count=Count('child_sample')) 

cnt1 = qs[0].c_count
cnt2 = qs[1].c_count
#...
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you could just loop over the queryset and sum up all the counts.

```
count = 0
for q in qs:
  count += q.c_count
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be:

```
cnt = ParentXX.objects.filter(name="xx").annotate(c_count=Count('child_sample')) 
cnt = ChildrenXX.objects.filter(name="xx").annotate(c_count=Count('parent_sample'))
```

'cnt' is a QuerySet Object,if you want get 'c_count', you can:

```
print(cnt[0].c_count)
```