# How to count foreign keys in django

Tags: python, django

I have a project with courses where every Course has Sections, and every Section has Videos, I want to count number of sections in each course, and count number of videos in each Section. How to implement that?

views

```
def CourseView(request,slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course,slug=slug)
    sections = CourseSections.objects.filter(course__title=course.title)
    videos = SectionVideos.objects.filter(section__course__title=course.title)
    return render(request,'courses/course_detail.html',{'course':course,'sections':sections,'videos':videos})
```

models

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CourseSections(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class SectionVideos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='courses/course_videos',max_length=100)
    section = models.ForeignKey(CourseSections,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django count of foreign key model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998591/django-count-of-foreign-key-model)

Comment: yes, but my sections already has filter, can i use annotate after that?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14327036/9374673) on using `count` or `len` depending on what you're doing with your queryset. If you plan on iterating over it anyways, then you might as well use `len` as it avoids the extra query from `count`. If all you want to do is get the number of elements in a queryset use those methods. Annotate is if you want something like a count of related videos for each section in your queryset.