# Django. How to reduce the number of database hits?

Tags: sql, django

Please tell me how can I reduce the number of requests, I will attach the code below:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    @property
    def views_count(self):
        return PostViews.objects.filter(post=self).count()

class PostViews(models.Model):
    IPAddres= models.GenericIPAddressField(default="111.222.333")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="post_views_count",)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IPAddres
```

**views.py**

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(is_toplevel=True, status=Post.ACTIVE).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags').select_related('category')
```

**html**

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ....
    {{ post.views_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Due to the postview call, the number of hits increases by 10 sql...

Comment: You can use `annotate` and generate a new attribute using `models.Count` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django count of foreign key model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998591/django-count-of-foreign-key-model)

Comment: yes what you need, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django annotation:

```py
queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_toplevel=True, status=Post.ACTIVE)
queryset = queryset.annotate(views_count=Count("post_views_count"))
queryset = queryset.select_related('author', 'category')
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('tags')
```

And remove your Post property in models.py